# Font awsome 3.0.1 documentation?

Tags: css, font-awesome

I looking for the docs of Font Awesome 3.0.1 as i'm working with a template using that version. And I can't seem to find the docs for the previous versions. Please Help!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Download the source code (as a **[zip](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/archive/v3.0.1.zip)** or **[tar.gz](https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome/archive/v3.0.1.tar.gz)**) and once extracted on your local system, browse to `Font-Awesome-3.0.1 > docs > index.html`

Answer (score 3):

You can just clone the repo and look at the index file:

```
git clone https://github.com/FortAwesome/Font-Awesome.git
cd Font-Awesome
git checkout v3.0.1
cd build
firefox index.html
```